# Use lambda functions that return json

Tags: javascript

For example:

```
alert([3,5].map(v=>{v:v}));
```

It thinks v:v is a function but I want it to be json. Is this possible?

Comment: please add what you want with `linq`.

Comment: linq is what I call the ES5 function stucture.

Comment: technically it's a [lambda expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function) and in javascript it's called [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: oh, sorry. I'll change it to lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap `{v:v}` with parenthesis.

```js
console.log([3,5].map(v=>({v:v})));
```